# Select data from json object using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mysql-json

I have a table containg two columns:

1. Customer id

   1. `json_data`  (it contains JSON object) is as follow

```json
{
  "nameValuePairs": {
    "CONTACTS": {
      "nameValuePairs": {
        "contacts": {
          "values": [
            {
              "nameValuePairs": {
                "contact_id": "1",
                "contact_phoneNumber": "080000016",
                "contact_phoneNumberCategory": "Mobile",
                "contact_firstName": "Huawei Customer Service",
                "contact_last_name": "Huawei Customer Service",
                "contact_title": "Huawei Customer Service",
                "contact_email": "mobile.pk@huawei.com"
              }
            },
            {
              "nameValuePairs": {
                "contact_id": "2",
                "contact_phoneNumber": "15",
                "contact_phoneNumberCategory": "Mobile",
                "contact_firstName": "Police Helpline",
                "contact_last_name": "Police Helpline",
                "contact_title": "Police Helpline"
              }
            },
            {
              "nameValuePairs": {
                "contact_id": "3",
                "contact_phoneNumber": "16",
                "contact_phoneNumberCategory": "Mobile",
                "contact_firstName": "Fire Brigade Helpline",
                "contact_last_name": "Fire Brigade Helpline",
                "contact_title": "Fire Brigade Helpline"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to extract information using MySQL such that I get the table such that

| Customer id | contact_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Huawei helpline |
| 1 | Police |

How can I get above  table? I need query

I try this query

```
JSON_EXTRACT(json_data, '$.nameValuePairs.CONTACTS.nameValuePairs.contacts.values[0]
                          .nameValuePairs.contact_title') AS "Contact name",
```

I am getting this table

| customer_id | contact_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ['Huawei helpline', 'Police', 'Fire Brigade'] |
| 2 | ['Huawei helpline', 'Police', 'Fire Brigade'] |

I don't want this table. I want one `contact_title` per row against the same `customer_id`

Comment: I don't see any way you could get that result with your query. You would only get that if you used `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`.

Comment: *I want one contact_title per row against same customer id* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html

Comment: What's the version of your DBMS ? Can you please tag it.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I am using MySQL . Can you solve this problem?

Comment: if the version is 8.0+ , then you can use JSON_TABLE()

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan can we use two or more JSON_Table() function because I have more than 2 columns.

Comment: sure, you can check out the answer

Answer (score 0):

If the DB version is `8.0+`, then you can use `JSON_TABLE()` function along with a *cross join* such as

```
SELECT contact_id, contact_title
  FROM `tab`
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                 `json_data`,
                 '$.nameValuePairs.CONTACTS.nameValuePairs.contacts.values[*]
                   .nameValuePairs' 
                  COLUMNS (
                           contact_id VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.contact_id'
                          )
       ) j1
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                  `json_data`,
                  '$.nameValuePairs.CONTACTS.nameValuePairs.contacts.values[*]
                    .nameValuePairs' 
                   COLUMNS (
                            contact_title VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.contact_title'
                           )
             ) j2
```

or a cleaner option might be

```
WITH t AS
(  
 SELECT contact_id, contact_title
   FROM `tab`
   JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                  `json_data`,
                  '$.nameValuePairs.CONTACTS.nameValuePairs.contacts.values[*]
                    .nameValuePairs' 
                   COLUMNS (
                            contact_id VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.contact_id',
                            contact_title VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.contact_title'
                           )
        ) AS j
)
SELECT t2.contact_id, t1.contact_title
  FROM t AS t1
  JOIN t AS t2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9DZqivsR)</kbd>